# C++ thread safe accessor and mutator

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an architect similar like below code.

```
struct Object {
  Object(int& n) : value{n} {}
  int& value;
}


struct Accessor {
  Accessor(const int& o) : o_(o) {}

  const int& getValue() {
   return o_;
  }

  private:
    const int& o_;
}

struct Mutator {
  Mutator(int& o) : o_(o) {}

  int& getValue() {
   return o_;
  }
  private:
    int& o_;
}

struct ObjectA : Object {
  shared_ptr<const Accessor> getAcc() {
    return make_shared<Accessor>(Accessor{value});

  shared_ptr<Mutator> getMut() {
    return make_shared<Mutator>(Mutator{value});
}
```

The goal is using mutator to be able to write object value and using accessor to read the object value.

I've wrote unit test and all tests are running fine.

I feel it may have an issue when running under multithread. I was wondering If the mutator and accessor thread safe? If not, how can I improve them to be thread safe?

Comment: You should start with removing the possibility of giving the client code a dangling reference, I believe

Comment: This depends heavily on how you use it. Do you lock while writing? Do you have lock-free algorithms only? (Do you know what a lock is and how it works?)

Comment: You need *synchronization* if you want to share a modifiable object with multiple threads.  That could something as like making the variable a `std::atomic` to using mutex around the modifying code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code you have shown is NOT thread-safe.

The way you have written the code, *any* thread can read/write the referenced `int` variable at *any* time without *any* synchronization between threads. While multiple threads can safely *read* from the `int` at the same time, bad things can happen if you allow a thread to *write* to the `int` at the same time that other threads are reading from the `int`, so you must *serialize* access so that the writing thread gets exclusive access to the `int`. Look at using `std::mutex`, `std::atomic`, or equivalent for that synchronization.

Also, the `int&` reference in `Object` is publicly accessible, and `ObjectA` inherits publicly from `Object`, so the referenced `int` is publicly accessible to all outside code, and thus *any* thread can just bypass your accessor/mutator completely.  If you want to enforce access to the `int` through them, make the `int` be private instead of public, and *don't* have the accessor/mutator return references to the `int`. That just allows callers to grab the reference and then access the `int` directly whenever they want.  Use methods or overloaded operators in your accessor/mutator classes to enforce that all access to the `int` goes through them only.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <mutex>

struct Object {
  Object(int& n) : value{n} {}
  int& value;
};

struct Accessor {
  Accessor(const int& o, std::mutex &m) : o_(o), m_(m) {}

  int getValue() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return o_;
  }

  /*
  operator int() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return o_;
  }
  */

  private:
    const int& o_;
    std::mutex& m_;
}

struct Mutator {
  Mutator(int& o, std::mutex &m) : o_(o), m_(m) {}

  void setValue(int value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    o_ = value;
  }

  /*
  Mutator& operator=(int value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    o_ = value;
    return *this;
  }
  */

  private:
    int& o_;
    std::mutex& m_;
};

struct ObjectA : private Object {

  ObjectA() : Object(value_) {}

  shared_ptr<Accessor> getAcc() const {
    return make_shared<Accessor>(value_, lock_);
  }

  shared_ptr<Mutator> getMut() {
    return make_shared<Mutator>(value_, lock_);
  }

  private:
    int value_ = 0;
    std::mutex lock_;
};

...

ObjectA o;
int val = o.getAcc()->getValue();
o.getMut()->setValue(val + 5);
/*
int val = *(o.getAcc());
*(o.getMut()) = val + 5;
*/
```

That being said, why are you using `std::shared_ptr`?  It is not necessary in this kind of code.  Your getter/mutator can just return its class objects by value instead of by dynamic pointer, eg:

```
#include <mutex>

struct Object {
  Object(int& n) : value{n} {}
  int& value;
};

struct Accessor {
  Accessor(const int& o, std::mutex &m) : o_(o), m_(m) {}

  int getValue() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return o_;
  }

  /*
  operator int() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return o_;
  }
  */

  private:
    const int& o_;
    std::mutex& m_;
}

struct Mutator {
  Mutator(int& o, std::mutex &m) : o_(o), m_(m) {}

  void setValue(int value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    o_ = value;
  }

  /*
  Mutator& operator=(int value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    o_ = value;
    return *this;
  }
  */

  private:
    int& o_;
    std::mutex& m_;
};

struct ObjectA : private Object {

  ObjectA() : Object(value_) {}

  Accessor getAcc() {
    return Accessor{value_, lock_};
  }

  Mutator getMut() {
    return Mutator{value_, lock_};
  }

  private:
    int value_ = 0;
    std::mutex lock_;
};

...

ObjectA o;
int val = o.getAcc().getValue();
o.getMut().setValue(val + 5);
/*
int val = o.getAcc();
o.getMut() = val + 5;
*/
```

Though, I wouldn't really suggest using separate access/mutator classes at all in this situation, as they are kind of redundant, eg:

```
#include <mutex>

struct Object {
  Object(int& n) : value{n} {}
  int& value;
};

struct ObjectA : private Object {

  ObjectA() : Object(value_) {}

  int getValue() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
    return value_;
  }

  void setValue(int value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
    value_ = value;
  }

  private:
    int value_ = 0;
    mutable std::mutex lock_;
};

...

ObjectA o;
int val = o.getValue();
o.setValue(val + 5);
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <atomic>

struct Object {

  int getValue() const {
    return value_;
  }

  void setValue(int value) {
    value_ = value;
  }

  private:
    std::atomic<int> value_{0};
};

...

Object o;
int val = o.getValue();
o.setValue(val + 5);
```

Comment: I split them to two different classes because Accessor has const return value, while Mutator has non-const return value. One class can not support them together.

Comment: You don't need `const` when returning by value instead of by reference. Also, you *can* support both operations in a single class.

Comment: Sorry I missed some context. I need to make sure that the underneath object is the same one. Return by value would not obey that rule. Also the function name has to be the same.